# Who is the person the Sherlock special episode is dedicated to?

Tags: sherlock

The special New Years episode of *Sherlock*, *The Abominable Bride*, has the following dedication:

```
In Memory of Charlie Phillips
        1960 - 2015
```

Googling has turned out nobody obvious, so who is, or rather was, this person: a member of production, a personal friend of the creators?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[He was an editor on *Sherlock* who died in February last year](http://www.chortle.co.uk/news/2015/02/06/21794/comedy_editor_charlie_phillips_dies).

> Charlie Phillips, a TV comedy editor whose credits include Psychoville, Him and Her and Man Down, has died in his mid-fifties. Reece Shearsmith paid tribute on Twitter saying: ‘RIP Charlie Philips - our amazing editor of Psychoville; **BAFTA for his work on Sherlock** and one of the loveliest people I've known.’ His other credits included Saxondale, Shooting Stars, Rev, Dr Terrible’s House of Horrible, and This Is Jinsy.

Comment: Charlie was a great editor of programmes, trailers and commercials. Worked with him many times, and he was a genuinely lovely guy - and a great editor!

Comment: Yes Charlie was a brilliant editor and a really fine fellow - he edited a lot of my early stuff that I did in London with Matt Lipsey - so sad to hear about his demise, let's hope he's tweaking the stars above to make us all smile a little more x